# How can I simulate the simultaneous execution of multiple tasks in .Net?

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I would like to run several tasks simultaneously. To be clear, I desire that they be simultaneous, not merely parallel -- at any point in time, I want every task to have consumed an equal number of CPU cycles, within some tolerance. How is this best done in .Net?

Comment: You can not guarantee the number of CPU Cycles a thread will have, this is because the OS may block some threads but not others to run other programs (including the OS itself)

Comment: Do you just need the threads to be in lockstep with each other? If that is what you want, that can be easily done. Please add a explination of what you are trying to do that has this "equal number of CPU cycles" requirement and we can give you some options.

Comment: No, the threads don't need to be in lockstep with each other.

I'm running multiple simulations of an industrial process and displaying intermediate results while the simulations are ongoing. The user will be evaluating not only the results, but the performance of the different algorithms used. Therefore, it is inappropriate to show one set of results produced by a simulation using X seconds of CPU time alongside another set of results produced by a simulation using 2X seconds of CPU time. I need the simulations to be roughly simultaneous.

Comment: Then fix the problem statement as that comment is not at all apparent in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to measure this, [Wall Clock time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) and [CPU time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time). Most people will likely tell you to use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to measure the performance, but that may or may not be the number you want.

If all you care about is how long it took to execute in real time, use stopwatch, if you want to know how long the thread itself was running, this can be done with the Native API call [GetThreadTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237.aspx). Here is a article [on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ExecutionStopwatch.aspx) that uses it. Note that you won't be able to use the TPL for this, you will need to use real [Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) as the TPL it recycles threads so the times will not be the real execution times for the Task.

A second option is use [QueryThreadCycleTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684943.aspx). This will not give you the time, but it will give you the number of cycles the current thread has been executing, you can do one at the start and one at the end and subtract the two numbers. Note again `Task` reuses threads so that number may or may-not be reliable unless you use full Threads.

Be aware you can't just directly convert `cycles->seconds` due to the fact that many processors (especially mobile processors) do not run at a fixed speed so there is no constant number you could multiply by to get the elapsed time in seconds. But if you are using a processor that does not vary its speed it then would be a simple math problem to get wall clock time from the cycles.

Comment: Thank you; QueryThreadCycleTime sounds like exactly what I need. However, there is still one missing piece of the puzzle: Suppose I find that one thread has consumed more CPU cycles than another, and I want to correct the imbalance. How can I suspend a thread, now that Thread.Suspend is deprecated? I suppose I could implement Suspend and Resume methods my own classes, but Thread.Suspend and Thread.Resume would not require me to create those methods, and I wonder if they've been deprecated in favor of alternatives which also do not require them.

Comment: When you say "Suspend" do you mean pause the thread to start it later, or do you mean to kill the thread and stop it from further running?

Comment: To pause the thread and start it later. I just discovered Thread.Sleep. Perhaps that's what I need instead of Suspend and Resume.